# Sending an intent to tasker, from tasker

Tags: tasker, intents

I'm trying to follow this how-to: [Dynamic Home Button Behavior
 (GrogBase)](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/tasker/137kg1m6dk/dynamic-home-button-behavior), but I  am having problems sending and receiving an intent. 
Can anybody tell me how to format the intent to be sent by a task, to be received by tasker?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

The intent *sent* needs to be configured like this:

```
Action: net.dinglish.android.tasker.ACTIION_TASK
Cat: None
Extra:[task name]
Target: Broadcast Receiver
```

And the Receive intent profile needs to be set up like this:

```
Action: net.dinglish.android.tasker.ACTIION_TASK
Cat: alt
Cat: None
Priority: Normal
```

Then Tasker will react to an intent tasker sends to Tasker.